# Why Vishnu agrees to stay at Lakshmi's place after marriage?

Tags: vishnu, lakshmi

Lord *Vishnu* is married to *Lakhsmiji* . After marriage he preferred to stay with goddess *Lakshmiji* in the *Sea* . The *Sea* is considered as Father of *Lakshmiji*.

So what made lord *Vishnu* stay in the sea?

Comment: As far as I know lord Vishnu sleeps on a sea of milk and not on an ordinary sea...

Comment: @TheDictator Kubera is the son of sage Vishravas and his wife Ilavida, daughter of sage Bharadwaja.

Comment: Isn't lord Vishnu lives in Vaikuntha?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan agree... i have made change over that...

Comment: He was living in 'Khsir Sagar' as per Wikipedia with Lakshmiji... who seats near the legs of Vishnuji.

Comment: wasn't Vishnu living in Kshir-sagar even before his union with Laskhmi? @TheDictator, source please, if it's otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

May be your are referring to Lord Vishnu's leela about the [Nachiyar Koil](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/5356/what-scriptures-describe-the-story-of-vishnus-subservience-to-lakshmi-in-the?rq=1)
. You can read more about the temple and the preciding deities. It is said that the Lord appeared in Venkateshwara form to marry Lakhsmi, but as demanded by Lakshmi the Lord should stay with Her and not the opposite where the bride goes to the husband's house.
Probably [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/5356/what-scriptures-describe-the-story-of-vishnus-subservience-to-lakshmi-in-the?rq=1) 
question will further answer your doubt.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  The question is about Vishnu sleeping in the ocean, the ocean being the father of Lakshmi.  The question isn't related to Nachiyar Koil.

Comment: Please answer properly with citation. Don't just give reference of some citation also mention it by writing main contents here.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan What are you talking about, Lord Vishnu sleeps on Garbhodaka ocean, from when that great cosmic ocean became the father of Lakshmi?!

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Well, in addition to sleeping in the Garbhodaka ocean, Vishnu also sleeps in the ocean of milk (called Thiruparkadal in Tamil and associated with Shwetadvipa).  Lakshmi emerged out of the churning of the ocean of milk.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Lakshmi emerging out of that milk ocean doesn't make the ocean her father. There were many things that emerged out of the ocean. How can someone use the word 'father' if something emerges out of it?

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Well, generally that which creates you is your father.  Like all the beings that emerged from the body of Brahma are considered his children.  Similarly all the beings that emerged from the ocean of milk are considered the ocean god's children.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan So by that logic, milk ocean is Lakshmi's father and Vishnu is the father of that ocean because Vishnu created that ocean so Lakshmi's father's father is Vishnu.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Well, I'm not sure whether Vishnu created the ocean himself or it was created by someone else like Brahma or Varuna, but yes one way or the other Lakshmi is a descendant of Vishnu.  Even the other birth of Lakshmi, where she's the daughter of Bhrigu, makes her a descendant of Vishnu, because Bhrigu's father is Brahma and Brahma's father is Vishnu.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Creation story is there in the scriptures, at first Vishnu was lying on the waters. That water is this ocean. What I know is that Vishnu lies on 2 oceans - Ksheersagara and Garbhodaka ocean and it is highly unlikely that someone other than Vishnu would have created those.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Well, at least according to the Pancharatra texts the form of Vishnu who sleeps in the ocean of milk is called Vyuha Vasudeva, and he is not eternal - he is created and destroyed, in contrast to the eternal form of Vishnu known as Para Vasudeva.  So given that both the ocean of milk and Vyuha Vasudeva are periodically created, it wouldn't surprise me if the ocean of milk was created by Brahma.

Answer (score -1):

Vishnu stays his in his place Vaikunthaloka, just as our bhuloka has oceans Vishnuloka has Ksheerasagara. He stays there according to Puranaprakriya. The ocean where Lakshmi was born is situated in earth. This ocean is in Vaikuntha. The question itself is not right.

Comment: I am looking for the reason.As i have already mentioned that in my question